# input de tipo submit me recarga la pagina de mi modal

Tags: php, html

he tenido un problema con mi modal a la hora de querer redireccionarlo para actualizar un solo campo de texto, resulta que a la hora de presionar el input me recarga la pagina y no me actualiza el registro, aquí mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarControlCalendarioRecambioColchones<?php echo $idCalendarioRecambioColchones ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-warning text-light">
            <h6 class="modal-title">
                Informacion General<strong class=""> <?php echo $naveNombre ?></strong>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <form id="formularioEditar" action="../../../model/controlCalendarioRecambioColchones/u_calendarioRecambioColchones.php" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-body bg-light">
                <div class="bg-light p-2 shadow rounded-lg" id="jumboBorderWarning">
                    <div class="row bg-light shadow m-2 p-1 text-center rounded-lg">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Observacion</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row bg-light shadow m-2 p-1 text-center rounded-lg">
                        <div class="col">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="ingrese observacion general" name="observacionGeneral" cols="30" rows="3" maxlength="480" style="min-width: 100%"><?php echo $row['observacionGeneral'] ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="idCalendarioRecambioColchones" value="<?php echo $idCalendarioRecambioColchones ?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn bg-warning text-white" value="Actualizar" name="actualizarResumenRecambioColchones">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

la direccion url que le entrego es correcta y además solo me actualiza algunos registor y otros solo me recarga la pagina ¿a que se puede deber esto?

Comment: los input tipo submit se supone que hacen exactamente lo que describes... enviar a tu backend el request con el contenido del formulario ...

Comment: si quieres enviar informacion sin un subimit... entonces tendras que programar un boton y enviarlo mediante ajax ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Resulta que no me deja actualizar un modal en especifico, ahora agregué un nuevo modal y el que me estaba fallando ahora funciona jaja, pero el nuevo que implemente empezó a mostrar los mismos errores, tal vez no es el input.